# Numerical integration of spline function in semi-log space

Tags: python

Given x and y data, I'd like to fit a spline to the data and numerically integrate the following fit. Using `Univariate.Spline`, I get a nice linear fit for `log10(y)` vs `x`. I then integrate the resulting spline using `Univariate.Spline.integral(bounds)`. My problem is that I'm not sure how to interpret the output, given that I am working in semi-log space.

```
    y = np.array([1,10,100,1000])
    x = np.array([15,16,17,18])
    x_vals = np.linspace(0,50,1000)

    plt.scatter(x,np.log10(y))
    s = interpolate.UnivariateSpline(x,np.log10(y))
    plt.plot(x_vals,s(x_vals))

    print(s.integral(15,17))
```

Should I take `10^(s.integral(15,17)` to obtain the "true" value of the integral?

Answer (score 0):

You can numerically integrate a function of the interpolation

```
from scipy import interpolate, integrate

def antilog_s(x):
    return 10.0**s(x)

integrate.quad(antilog_s, 15, 17)
Out[16]: (42.99515370842196, 4.773420959438774e-13)
```